# Scrollpane won't resize to fit gridpane JavaFX

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, fxml

I am writing a program using JavaFX in which I have

Borderpane -> Center -> VBox -> ScrollPane-> Gridpane

I would like to be able to add as many rows to the gridpane as I like and have the scrollpane automatically extend itself.

**Note:** I have some very long files so I only included the important bits.  If you need the whole FXML or Controller file please leave me a comment.

Here is the FXML for my gridpane/scrollpane:

```
<BorderPane>        
<center>
<VBox>
<children>
<ScrollPane fx:id="messageScrollPane" vbarPolicy="ALWAYS" hbarPolicy="NEVER" hmax="0.0" vmax="0.0">
<content>
<GridPane fx:id="messageBox" prefHeight="540.0" prefWidth="589.0">
<columnConstraints>
<ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
<ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
</columnConstraints>
<rowConstraints>
<RowConstraints maxHeight="Infinity" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
<RowConstraints maxHeight="Infinity" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
<RowConstraints maxHeight="Infinity" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
<RowConstraints maxHeight="Infinity" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
<RowConstraints maxHeight="Infinity" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
<RowConstraints maxHeight="Infinity" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
<RowConstraints maxHeight="Infinity" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
</rowConstraints>
</GridPane>
</content>
</ScrollPane>
</children>
</VBox>
</center>
</BorderPane>
```

I have the following code inside of my Controller for the FXML

```
  @FXML
private GridPane messageBox;

 if (me.getMail().size() > 0) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < me.getMail().size(); i++) {
                                    messageBox.add(new Label(me.getMail().get(i).toString()), 0, rowNum);
                                    rowNum++;
                                }
                            }
```

Thank you all for your help!

Ryan

Comment: I wrote a simple description about the `ScrollPane` in the Documentation, try to use it, (hoping it will help you), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javafx/8259/scrollpane/26534/b-dynamic-contents-size#t=201702022233434993017)

Answer (score 0):

You have placed the ScrollPane inside a [VBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html).  You should [set the vgrow priority](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html#setVgrow-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.scene.layout.Priority-) for the ScrollPane to [Priority.ALWAYS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Priority.html#ALWAYS) to allow the ScrollPane to grow to fill the available area of the VBox.

You can do this in FXML by adding the following attribute:

```
VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS"
```

to the `<ScrollPane VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" ...>` element

Alternatively, you can do it in code via:

```
VBox.setVgrow(scrollPane, Priority.ALWAYS);
```

---

Also, a separate issue with your code is that you are adding rows dynamically (in a loop in code) to your grid pane.  If you wish to do that, you should define `RowConstraints` in your FXML (as FXML cannot contain a variable number of rows).  Instead, apply row constraints within your loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < me.getMail().size(); i++) {
    messageBox.add(new Label(me.getMail().get(i).toString()), 0, rowNum);
    rowNum++;
    messageBox.getRowConstraints().add(new RowConstraints(...));
}
```

Comment: what does the RowConstraints do? Also I added the RowConstraints and removed the ones defined in my FXML and set the VBox.vgrow="Always" and still it still won't grow the VBox or Scrollpane.  Any more ideas? I appreciate your help!